# Can't figure out how to properly use easing function

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, easing, easing-functions

I really need help to figure out on how to use these easing functions I found on this helpful website: https://spicyyoghurt.com/tools/easing-functions

I know what the values that the function needs means, I created a function in one of my classes that helps me get the current time (t) to pass it to the function afterwards:

```
getEaseTimeVar()
{
    var timeStamp = performance.now();
    this.#secondsPassed = (timeStamp - this.#oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
    this.#oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;

    return timeStamp;
}
```

**(EXPLANATION)**
This function works, but only if it is called at the beginning of the code execution. For example, if I want to fade something in (value from 0 to 1) using a linear easing function and call it at the beginning of code execution, it would increase and even go beyond 1, which is fine, that's normal. However, if I want to do the same thing, but I want it to start say 5 seconds after code execution, it will not start at 0, but jump to a larger value.

**(PROBLEM)**
This is because I think I am not getting the time at which the animation starts, but from the start of all code execution, and I am struggling to understand how to do this while still maintaining a simple function to use the easing animation.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Animation start time

You need to keep track of the animation start time.

Then use the difference between current time from start time (`animTime`).

Only animate while the animTime is between 0 and animation duration.

### Example

```js
// From https://spicyyoghurt.com/tools/easing-functions
const easeLinear = (t, b, c, d) => c * t / d + b;
const easeInOutQuad = (t, b, c, d) => (t /= d * 0.5) < 1 ? c * 0.5 * t * t + b : -c * 0.5 * ((t - 1) * (t - 3) - 1) + b;

var animating = false;
var startTime;
const animDuration = 2000; // ms
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.addEventListener("click",() => {
    startTime = performance.now(); 
    !animating && requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); 
});

function mainLoop(time) {
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     if (startTime) {
         var animTime = time - startTime;
         // or var animTime = performance.now() - startTime

         const x = easeLinear(animTime, -20, canvas.width + 40, animDuration);
         const y = easeInOutQuad(animTime, 20, canvas.height - 40, animDuration);         
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
         ctx.fill();
         if (animTime < animDuration) {
             requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
             animating = true;
         } else {
             animating = false;
         }
     }

}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
Click canvas to start / restart animation.<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```